QML client side shadow
There are some examples on SO on client side shadows for QML frameless windows. However giving your shadow a larger size, like e.g. 80px, imposes heavy load on your GPU. Now I wonder if it is possible to cache the shadow. The obvious solution is to cache: true. However using QSG_VISUALIZE=changes and the system monitor tell me that it is redrawn.
Even using a layer effect where the layered source pixmap does not change the effect is redrawn. Even if not a single child item changed the effect will be rendered again.
How can I effectively cache the output of a GraphicsEffect in QML until the source pixmap does actually change? Even better, if I can assure that the source does not change unless the geometry changes, how can I manually trigger rendering the effect?

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that the way the shadow is drawn depends on the platform capabilities, and may always require repainting under certain conditions, possibly because it has to compose the shadow with what appears "behind" the window.

DropShadow is a non-trivial graphical effect. Often, I look to see if I can mimick the behavior say, with a Rectangle with rounded corners and opacity set, then, I can significantly lighten the load with minimal observed differences.
